# how to check for returning customers in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following sales data, split by customer and year:

|  | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2018 |
| customer 2 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 2018 |
| customer 3 | 100 | 0 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 100 | this is tricky, let's say 2021 |
| customer 4 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 100 | 0 | this is tricky, let's say 2020 |

My goal is to track when a customer "returns" by to us, after not buying for a year (see expected results column).

I'm using excel 2013, so cannot use MAXIFS.

The other issue is, sometimes there are two gaps (see customer 3 & 4). In this case, I'd take the most recent gap/return.

Any ideas how to manage this?

Comment: Did the customer 2 return the wrong result? The customer 2 expected result should be 2019, rigtht?

Comment: @Lee I think the result is ok in the question. "when a customer "returns" by to us, after not buying for a year" in 2018 it's a returning customer, in 2019 customer 2 is a permanent customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

`= MAX(IF((C2:H2>0)*(B2:G2=0),$C$1:$H$1,0))`

Take care to shift the range in the conditions.

[image]

Comment: thankyou, it's working very well!

Comment: NICE ! I was so close with my answer, what exactly is the *(B2:G2=0) part doing ?

Comment: so, the first part is checking for the Max year where we had a sale (>0), and the second part is checking for the max year where there is no sale (=0), and the last part gives the column (year). 

Though I understand the code, it's still magic somehow lol

Comment: @egg yes, your understanding is correct.  You can evaluate the formula and it might help to better understand how it works.

Comment: @PeterH it's checking for previous year purchase to be 0

Comment: oh and the two ranges are slightly apart (C:H vs B:G) to match the situation of "first find the no sales, then find the sales right after"... right? :)